# Stop fetching JSON after X lines scanned in, in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsurl

I am making a new iOS application in Objective-C. My application utilizes an API that provides JSON data. The problem is there are hundreds of JSON objects in the list, and no way to narrow the search using the API. I only want the first ten, but when I scan them **all** in it takes forever.

**Is there a way to only scan in the first 10 (or whatever number) JSON objects and stop?**

Here is my current code fetching all the data.

```
- (void)fetchCodeForces {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *requestString = @"https://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *datatask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        _f1 = json[@"result"];

        for (NSDictionary *d in _f1) {
            if ([d[@"phase"] isEqualToString:@"BEFORE"])
            {
                [_fetched addObject:d];
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });



    }];
    [datatask resume];
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger findedPhase = 0;
for (NSDictionary *d in _f1) {
            if ([d[@"phase"] isEqualToString:@"BEFORE"] && findedPhase < 10)
            {
                [_fetched addObject:d];
                 findedPhase += 1;
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

This add to your _fetched array only the 10 first "before" phases (or less). Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: The for loop is not reason it is going slowly. The reason is the fetching of all the data, what I am looking for is a way to not fetch all the data just some of it.